Random adjacendy matrix from list of degrees
I want to do exactly the same thing as this post, but in python; aka given a list of natural integers, generate a random adjacency matrix whose degrees would match the list.
I had great hope as the solution proposed uses a function from igraph, sample_degseq. However it seems like this function does not exist in the python version of igraph, at least as far as looked into it.
I could program such a function myself but I'm not exactly smart enough to make it fast enough, and I would like this to be done in an efficient way.

I should note that I am actively working on improving this specific area of functionality in igraph. We will consider feedback about what features are needed the most (extensions to non-simple graphs or bipartite graphs while maintaining uniformity, handling connected graphs, etc.)

The equivalent of R/igraph's sample_degseq() in python-igraph is Graph.Degree_Sequence(). Note that not all methods sample uniformly, and not all methods produce the same kind of graph (simple graph vs multigraph).
"configuration_simple" and "edge_switching_simple" sample simple graphs uniformly. The former is exactly uniform (but very slow for anything but small degrees) and the latter almost exactly uniform.
I recommend "edge_switching_simple". It basically generates a first graph using Graph.Realize_Degree_Sequence(), then it rewires it using rewire(), using 10 times as many steps as the number of edges.

Have you had a look at the package random_graph ? It appears to do precisely what you want, though I haven’t tested it myself.
